# How to sum up values from all hashes?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

How to sum up values from all hashes more elegantly than I do it?
`boards_statistics` array contains `items_info` hashes.

```
def generate_accumulated_statistics(boards_statistics)
  # Create hash with zero values - its purprose is to
  # accumulate results from all other hashes
  resulted_hash = {
    items_info: {
      finished_items: {
        todo: 0,
        in_progress: 0,
        done: 0
      },

      hours_worked: {
        estimated: 0,
        time_logged: 0
      },

      story_points_completed: {
        estimated: 0,
        completed: 0
      },

      due_today_items: 0,
      late_items: 0
    },
    team_info: []
  }

  boards_statistics.each do |statistics|
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:finished_items][:todo] += statistics[:items_info][:finished_items][:todo]
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:finished_items][:in_progress] += statistics[:items_info][:finished_items][:in_progress]
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:finished_items][:done] += statistics[:items_info][:finished_items][:done]

    resulted_hash[:items_info][:hours_worked][:estimated] += statistics[:items_info][:hours_worked][:estimated]
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:hours_worked][:time_logged] += statistics[:items_info][:hours_worked][:time_logged]

    resulted_hash[:items_info][:story_points_completed][:estimated] += statistics[:items_info][:story_points_completed][:estimated]
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:story_points_completed][:completed] += statistics[:items_info][:story_points_completed][:completed]

    resulted_hash[:items_info][:due_today_items] += statistics[:items_info][:due_today_items]
    resulted_hash[:items_info][:late_items] += statistics[:items_info][:late_items]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking how to do something that works more elegantly is a code-review and belongs on [codereview.se] rather than [so] which is for code problems.

Comment: A quickie: `resulted_hash.to_s.scan(/=>\K\d+/).reduce(0) { |tot, s| tot + s.to_i } #=> 0`. Having all zeros is not the best example. "result_hash" or "resulting_hash" would be a better name, as "resulted" is a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own flavor of deep merging. Here:

```
class ::Hash
  def deep_merge(second)
    merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : (v1+v2) }
    self.merge(second, &merger)
  end
end

resulted_hash
# => {:items_info=>{:finished_items=>{:todo=>0, :in_progress=>0, :done=>0}, :hours_worked=>{:estimated=>0, :time_logged=>0}, :story_points_completed=>{:estimated=>0, :completed=>0}, :due_today_items=>0, :late_items=>0}, :team_info=>[]}

boards_statistics
#  => {:items_info=>{:finished_items=>{:todo=>1, :in_progress=>1, :done=>1}, :hours_worked=>{:estimated=>1, :time_logged=>1}, :story_points_completed=>{:estimated=>1, :completed=>1}, :due_today_items=>1, :late_items=>1}, :team_info=>[]}

resulted_hash = resulted_hash.deep_merge(boards_statistics)
# => {:items_info=>{:finished_items=>{:todo=>1, :in_progress=>1, :done=>1}, :hours_worked=>{:estimated=>1, :time_logged=>1}, :story_points_completed=>{:estimated=>1, :completed=>1}, :due_today_items=>1, :late_items=>1}, :team_info=>[]}

resulted_hash = resulted_hash.deep_merge(boards_statistics)
# => {:items_info=>{:finished_items=>{:todo=>2, :in_progress=>2, :done=>2}, :hours_worked=>{:estimated=>2, :time_logged=>2}, :story_points_completed=>{:estimated=>2, :completed=>2}, :due_today_items=>2, :late_items=>2}, :team_info=>[]}
```